# How can I get the original datatype of the values after using f.coalesce in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, types, casting

```
list = ["B", "A", "D", "C"]

data = [("B", "On","NULL",1632733508,"active"),
        ("B", "Off","NULL",1632733508, "active"), 
        ("A","On","NULL",1632733511,"active"),    
        ("A","Off","NULL",1632733512,"active"),
        ("D","NULL",450,1632733513,"inactive"),
        ("D","NULL",431,1632733515,"inactive"),
        ("C","NULL",20,1632733518,"inactive"),
        ("C","NULL",30,1632733521,"inactive")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["unique_string", "ID", "string_value", "numeric_value", "timestamp","mode"])
```

For splitting a df according to a List I have the following code.

```
    split_df = (df.filter(
                f.col('listname') == list)
                .select(
                f.coalesce(f.col('string_value'), 
                f.col('double_value')).alias(list), 
                f.col('timestamp'), f.col('mode')
               ))
               return split_df


dfs = [split_df(df, list) for id in list]
```

Startpoint

```
    ID  string_value    numeric_value   timestamp   mode   
0   B   On              NULL            1632733508  active
1   B   Off             NULL            1632733508  active
2   A   On              NULL            1632733511  active
3   A   Off             NULL            1632733512  active
4   D   NULL            450             1632733513  inactive
5   D   NULL            431             1632733515  inactive
6   C   NULL            20              1632733518  inactive
7   C   NULL            30              1632733521  inactive
```

After using the Function split_df there is a list of df like this below.

```
dfs[1].show()

    D   timestamp   mode
0   450 1632733513  inactive
1   431 1632733515  inactive
```

After using **f.coalesce** all values in each column will be a string. This is not good in the case of a numeric variable like ID "D". As printSchema shows is the ID "D" a string and not a double and the "timestamp" also a string and not a long.

```
dfs[1].printSchema()

root
 |-- D: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- mode: string (nullable = true)
```

What do I have to do with the function to keep the original data types?

Comment: If you are doing a generic process, you need to have a generic schema, which includes a unique string column. Can't you just cast it back to double after ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just [cast](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.cast) it to whatever datatype you want, so something like

```
f.coalesce(
  f.col('str_col'),
  f.col('int_col'),
).cast('int')
```